# Double sum divergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, double-sequence

I have been trying to prove
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m+n)^2}=\infty
$$

I tried interchanging the sums, but the problem essentially same. I am also aware that: For $a_{m,n}\in [0,\infty]$
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{m,n}\bigg)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{\psi(k)}
$$
where $\psi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is a bijection. 
I could not find a way an appropriate $\psi$ to show that the latter one diverges. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try thinking combinatorially of how many m,n there are that add up to a given k, and replace the double sum with a single index related to this.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m+n)^2}\geq \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{(m+n)^2}\geq\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{(2m)^2}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4m}$$

Comment: This assumes that the sum to $\infty$ has meaning.

Comment: @martycohen: you can always work with finite sum and pass to the limit, or just argue by comparison.

Comment: Sums with positive terms always have meanings.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
s(N)
&=\sum_{m=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{(m+n)^2}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^N\sum_{n=m+1}^{m+N} \frac{1}{n^2}\\
&\gt\sum_{m=1}^N\sum_{n=m+1}^{m+N} \frac{1}{n^2}\\
&\ge\sum_{m=1}^N\sum_{n=m+1}^{m+N} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\\
&\ge\sum_{m=1}^N\sum_{n=m+1}^{m+N}(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n})\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^N(\frac1{m}-\frac1{m+N})\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^N\frac1{m}-\sum_{m=1}^N\frac1{m+N}\\
&\gt\sum_{m=1}^N\frac1{m}-\sum_{m=1}^N\frac1{1+N}\\
&\gt\sum_{m=1}^N\frac1{m}-\frac{N}{1+N}\\
&\gt\sum_{m=1}^N\frac1{m}-1\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\sum_{m=1}^N\frac1{m}$
diverges,
so does
$s(N)$.

Note that
this only works with finite sums,
so there are no problems with
rearrangements or
splitting a sum into two parts.